# Add Glow Effect Around my custom marker in Android Google Map v2

Tags: android, google-maps

I am stuck in this task of adding custom marker with glow. I have attached my desired Image. I am Wondering about to find solution but not able to solve.
 marker code which i am using is this.

```
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title(title)
            .position(points)
            .snippet(snippet)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(res))
        ).showInfoWindow();
```

[image]

I don't want to use any extra Image. I want to do it through code
 ,help me please. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw a normal custom marker bitmap over the glow effect(only) bitmap.

That should look something like this:

```
        int resourceIdCar = R.drawable.car;
        Bitmap bmpCar = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resourceIdCar);
        int resourceIdArrow = R.drawable.arrow;
        Bitmap bmpArrow = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resourceIdArrow);

        Bitmap bmpOverlay = overlay(bmpCar,bmpArrow);
        myMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(DerekPos)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                        .title("Hello world")
                        .draggable(true)
                                //.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.car))
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmpOverlay))
        );

//=-=-=-=-=-=-=

private Bitmap overlay(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2) {
    Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(), bmp1.getHeight(), bmp1.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, new Matrix(), null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, new Matrix(), null);
    return bmOverlay;
}
```

[image]